# Array of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, pointers

In the question below I not getting the **bold** line. Does that line mean create an array objects of class compartment? Because as per my knowledge Java doesn't have concept of pointers.

Create an abstract class compartment to represent a rail coach. Provide an abstract function notice in the class. Derive FirstClass, General, Ladies and Luggage classes from the Compartment class. Override notice function in each of them.
Create a class TestCompartment. Write main function to do the following:
**Declare an array of compartment pointers of size 10.**

Comment: "Reference" and "pointer" are the same thing.  (It is very poorly phrased.  Whoever wrote it should get a "D".)

Comment: (JLS 4.3.1 Line 2) The reference values (often just references) are pointers to these objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On one hand, Java does not have a concept of pointers; on the other hand, everything other than primitives in Java (i.e. all `Object`-derived things) could be through of as "pointers", although technically they are not called that.

Java calls them *references*, but since there is such thing as `null` reference, they behave very much like pointers in C and C++.

Anyway, when you create an array of ten non-primitives, you create an array of references, each one set to `null`:

```
Compartment[] compartments = new Compartment[10];
```

This is different from creating ten `Compartment` objects, in that the objects themselves are not created when you create an array, only places through which you could reference these objects later if you need to.

Comment: Well, in Java there *is* a null reference :-)

Answer (score 0):

It most likely means: create a size 10 array of **references**.

Comment: What does references exactly mean? Should we create objects?

Comment: @Lizzie - If it says create the array, presumably you just create the array -- the values will be `null`.  But as I said above, it's a very poorly phrased statement.

Comment: A references is the type of the var in `Compartement con;`  con is a reference to a Compartement object but until you create the object it points to null

Answer (score 0):

Java has no pointers as such.Everything that's not a primitive is a reference.

Comment: And what's the difference between a "reference" and a "pointer"?

Comment: @HotLicks: One thing exists, the other doesn't. What's the difference between something that exists and something that doesn't?

Comment: @HotLicks Adding to Kerrek,If you defenetly need it, AFAIK the difference is we can not arithmetic operations on references.we can on pointers

Comment: @Baadshah - You can do arithmetic on pointers *in some languages*.

Answer (score 0):

Although the underlying implementation of references in Java comes down to C-like pointers (because it does, at some point), I think references would have been a better way of putting through the request.

You only have to declare a classic array.

Comment: References are not always implemented with pointers in java. The current 64 bit jvm from Oracle does have a mode, where references are stored as 32 bit values, which are then shifted 2 times before usage. Thus only using 32 bit for each reference, but still allowing access to 16GB ram.

Comment: @MTilsted - And there have been cases of pointers implemented with similar manipulations.